# Will the memory usage and/or database size double during database migration in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, migration, database-migration

SQLite [suggests](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) creating & populating a new table and deleting the old one as ALTER TABLE statements are quite limited.

My question is, will the memory and/or database size double during database migration in SQLite, as at some point during the migration, there will be two distinct tables which contain the exact same data, and maybe even a bit more.

Do I need to ensure that I have enough memory and/or disk space to be able to complete the operation successfully, or will SQLite optimize the transaction and reduce the resources needed? Is there a way to estimate how much resources such a migration operation will take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have filled the new table and not yet deleted the old table, you have both sets of data in your database, so need disk space for both.

Additionally, when you then delete the old table, the old version of all changed data is written to the rollback journal to allow the transaction to be rolled back, so the required disk space actually triples.

Comment: "Additionally, when you then delete the old table, the old version of all changed data is written to the rollback journal to allow the transaction to be rolled back, so the required disk space actually triples."

I never imagined that, thanks!